# PreCondition or PostCondtion in ACSL

Tags: frama-c

I am not able to distinguish between various precondition and post-condition in ACSL. As I know that requires, terminates and assume comes in precondition and ensures and assigns in post-condition. But in which set rest like decrease etc are??

Can any body is able to help me in figuring out??
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a trick question. Basically, `decreases` would serve as a pre-condition of a recursive call: if you have a function `f` with `decreases x;`, if it happens to make a call to itself, you have to prove that `x<\at(x,Pre)` at this call site. Additionally, you have a pre-condition that `x>=0` when you call `f` (recursive call or not).
Regarding other clauses (based on their order of apperance in [ACSL 1.7](http://frama-c.com/download/acsl_1.7.pdf):

- `complete` and `disjoint` clause are basically a logical property of the `assumes` clause of the contract, they do not imply anything for the implementation, but act as a sanity check of the specification itself.
- `allocates` and `frees` are post-conditions (like for `assigns` but regarding dynamic allocation)
- `exits` (and `returns`, `breaks` and `continues`) are post-conditions (they are evaluated when we exit the function -or the statement).
- dependencies (`\from`) are post-conditions (like `assigns`).

Comment: if decreases is pre-condition then what will it check when the function will be called for first time?

Comment: Only that the expression given to `decreases` is non-negative. That's why I speak about a "pre-condition of a _recursive_ call" (it could also be seen as `assert` at each call site inside `f`).

Answer (score 2):

decrease clause of ACSL is basically used for recursive function calls.
if you have specified decrease clause with a pointer variable x like: decrease *x;
then what it means is, every time when control enters the function related to this decrease clause, it checks whether the value pointed to by the pointer x is 1 less as compared to the value pointed to by x during the pre-state of the function. For the very first time when the function is called, pre-condition checked is: (*x) >= 0 as the function is in its pre-state so there is no pre-state value to compare to.